# Very small, limited-to-javax.inject dependency injection framework for Java

Tags: java

Is there any small DI framework out here that implements the [`javax.inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html) package (bar the `@Scope` annotation: `@Singleton` is enough) and provides only a container around it to get instances from? This framework will be embedded with my framework in other small applications, so I can't affort to have much features, or size. More features means more support from me which I don't want either. Even a "go see the  documentation" is too much support for this project.

#### Features required:

- implements `javax.inject`
- constructor injection

#### Optional features:

- less reflection as possible, including proxy

#### What did I do already?

I know the following ones, but most provide way too much stuff with them and therefore a clog of APIs that I don't want/need.

- Dagger: current first choice for this project. Remove the modules and that's what I'm looking for (yes, that means no interface). A size of 58kb is excellent compared to other frameworks. The compile-time injection is the cherry on the cake.
- Guice: always my first choice when it comes to DI, but it's too big for this project, especially in terms of API.
- Spring: I said small...
- HK2: don't know enough to properly judge, but it looks like it has most of Guice's features.
- Pico-container: isn't really "pico" anymore, at least in terms of API.

Comment: What about the CDI reference implementation, [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/)?

Comment: I never used it outside of an application server, but the fact that it has so many options make it clear it's not a real contender in my search. This can be seen here: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.2/

Comment: Try hk2 (http://hk2.java.net).  It is not as small as it used to be but it is still relatively small compared to many others